# Drupal 7 Unable to remove/update uploaded file in content type

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a content type "Product" and I want it to be possible to attach a PDF to nodes of this content type for visitors to download, so I created a custom field "download" on this content type.

The type and widget of this field are both "file" and in admin I have the possibility to upload / remove a file... or at least, it seems so. Initially uploading a PDF is not a problem, it will be added to the node. But if I later try to remove the file - no can't do. I can easily press the "remove" button in the admin section, and then press "save", it doesn't give me an error and the "download" field is still empty. But if I refresh the page - Bam! there is my file again.

If I do both the remove action and uploading a new file at the same time, then again; I can press "save", it doesn't give me an error and the filename in the "download" field is the name of my new file. The new file is also uploaded. But again - after refreshing the page, the original, first file is back.

I chmodded my /files/ directory even to 777 for testing purposes, doesn't solve the issue. Anyone else any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can find some clues in the logs, don't you see anything related to your problem at /admin/reports/dblog ? Do you have access to the PHP logs of your web server ? If so, have a look too.

Comment: nothing in /admin/reports/dblog, also nothing useful in PHP logs

Answer (score 0):

After checking your php logs I would also check that your .htaccess files are setup correctly. Its possible your apache environment is not allowing drupal to generate the correct settings.

Comment: checked, everything looks fine there as well